# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug’: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After I added the Play Services GCM dependency gradle,  it wouldn't build anymore. I get this error during the build

> - Sync: OK
> - Make Project: OK
> - Clean: OK
> - Run: Error
>
> app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug’:com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/annotation/AnimatorRes.class

This issue may be conflict among the libraries. So I did tried excluding support-V4 conflicts from the newly added gradles. Still problem persists.

This issue is quite possibly due to exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android. So i tried cleaning the project, and removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build. Gradle, OR by adding multidex support

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.widevision.dressnroom"
    minSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
}



dependencies {
compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.25.10.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/okhttp-2.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/joda-time-2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile files('libs/anjlab-iabv3-current.jar')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }

compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }


}
```